# Nginx - Rewrite the request_uri before uwsgi_pass

Tags: regex, nginx, uwsgi, bottle

I have a Nginx vhost than is configured as such:

```
...
location /one {
  include uwsgi_params;
  uwsgi_pass unix:///.../one.sock;
}
location /two {
  include uwsgi_params;
  uwsgi_pass unix:///.../two.sock
}
...
```

*This is a simplified configuration of course*

When I request `/one/something` I would like my Python script to receive `/something` as `request_uri`.

I'm using BottlePy but would like this to be handled by Nginx and not in my Python code.

Can I do something like `uwsgi_param REQUEST_URI replace($request_uri, '^/one', '')`?

**Edit**

Here is the request from my Python code:

[pid: 30052|app: 0|req: 1/1]  () {42 vars in 844 bytes} [Tue Aug 21 14:22:07 2012] GET /one/something => generated 0 bytes in 4 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 2 headers in 85 bytes (0 switches on core 0)

So Python is OK but uWSGI is not.

How to fix that?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
location /one {
  rewrite /one/(.+) /$1 break;
  include uwsgi_params;
  uwsgi_pass unix:///.../one.sock;
}
```

Comment: if one uses this rule: `rewrite /one/?(.*)$ /$1 break;`, the route `https://<hostname>/one` (without trailing `/`) will also work.

Comment: @netzego - Eh, neither `/one` nor `/one/` are valid URLs though, so why permit it? They want to end up receiving the `/something` that comes afterwards. IDK, just thinking about my own application right now.

Answer (score 3):

I know this thread is old, but there is another way to solve this if you are using  uWSGI to run your python app.

```
[uwsgi]
route-uri = ^/one/(.*) rewrite:/$1
```

Comment: What's the meaning of $1 here?

Comment: $1 represents the first capture in the regular expression, from left to right, in this case (.*). If you had more captures, you could have $2, $3 and so on.

Comment: try `route-uri = ^/one/?(.*)$ rewrite:/$1` and `https://<hostname>/one` without trailing a slash, will also work,

Comment: Good catch @netzego

Answer (score 1):

I just met the same problem, and here is a solution

```
location /one {
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass unix:///.../one.sock;
    uwsgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /one;
    uwsgi_modifier1 30;
}
```

You can found more about `uwsgi_modifier1` here: 
http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Nginx.html#hosting-multiple-apps-in-the-same-process-aka-managing-script-name-and-path-info

Comment: The documentation that's linked in your answer now explicitly says *not* to do what you've shown (and it says "ancient uWSGI versions used to support " it, suggesting it's no longer supported).

Answer (score 0):

I've solved that in another way:

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi:application
master = true
processes = 10
socket = 127.0.0.1:9090
mount = /one=customscript.py
manage-script-name = true
```

nginx

```
location /one {
  include uwsgi_params;
  uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9090;
}
```