# Nginx default website path in subdirectory rather than / (root)

Tags: nginx, webserver, nginx-config

I want to configure my site so it runs in a subdirectory rather than `mydomain/`. I mean instead of going to mysite.com/ and seeing the website, I want it to be seen from `mydomain/myproject`.
I am using `uwsgi` to talk to a flask website and here is my `/etc/nginx/sites-available/myproject` config file.

```
server {
    server_name mydomain www.mydomain;

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/root/Desktop/myproject/myproject.sock;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
server {
    if ($host = www.mydomain) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = mydomain) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain www.mydomain;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

I tried to change the code from `location /` to `location /myproject` or `location = /myproject` but it gave me not found!

**Added information**
Here is my `config.ini` file

```
[uwsgi]
module = server:app

master = true
processes = 5

socket = myproject.sock
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true

die-on-term = true

route-run = fixpathinfo:
```

I am using **uwsgi** version 2.0.18 and **nginx**/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this...

NGINX config:

```
location /mylocation {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/myproject/myproject.sock;
        uwsgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /mylocation;
    }
```

uwsgi ini file:

```
route-run = fixpathinfo:
```

Edit:
i tried it with rewriting the path in my nginx config and it worked.. nothing special to configure in your wsgi ini file!

```
location /be {
    rewrite /be/(.+) /$1 break;
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/myproject/myproject.sock;

    }
```

**EDIT**: So, my conclusion is, fixpathinfo in uwsgi ini seems not to work when using "/" (root) inside FlaskApp. If Flask is using "/", you should set `rewrite /be/(.*) /$1 break;` in your NGINX Config

Thank you CyberDem0n!! 
[Nginx - Rewrite the request_uri before uwsgi_pass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12054001/nginx-rewrite-the-request-uri-before-uwsgi-pass)

Comment: what is `fixpathinfo`?

Comment: it still gives `not found`

Comment: This action allows you to set SCRIPT_NAME in nginx without bothering to rewrite the PATH_INFO (something nginx cannot afford)   https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Changelog-2.0.11.html

Comment: have you tried to configure a mountpoint in your ini file? like mount = /app1=app1.py?

Comment: stupid question... but have you restarted your nginx AND app service after changing nginx config and ini file? which version of uwsgi/nginx do you have?

Comment: also check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12054001/nginx-rewrite-the-request-uri-before-uwsgi-pass

Comment: I added extra info about `config.ini` file. In addition I restart nginx everytime I make changes, so yes!

Comment: so strange... it should work. you also did "systemctl restart myproject" (myproject.service socket)? see my edit... have you also tried the second solution (rewrite path in nginx with "rewrite /myproject/(.+) /$1 break;"?

Comment: Yes I did restart both socket and nginx. I do it everytime for every change and of course I did change `rewrite` path as you stated but I get not found. Do I have to configure flask router?

Comment: aaahh... i think i know where it is... i think you are using "/" (root) in your flaskapp right? so change "rewrite /myproject/(.+) /$1 break;"  to "rewrite /myproject/ / break;"

Comment: please can you set "rewrite_log on;" in your nginx server config and then post the log in /var/log/nginx/error.log ?

Comment: Dude `rewrite /myproject/ / break;` solved the problem and yes I was using `/` in my flask app! ‌But the problem is now my app gives not found and sending ajax requests results in not found error and everything is not working.

Comment: so, try ```rewrite /myproject/(.*) /$1 break;```